# Responder still catching hashes with LLMNR and Netbios over TCP/IP disabled. Is this by design?

Tags: hash, windows, smb

My responder is still catching hashes from Windows 10 box that has had Netbios over TCP/IP (DHCP scope option) and LLMNR disabled (GP).

The workstation invokes the net view \\responderip and responder displays the hash.  Please confirm this is by design.  Probably is meant to protect against broadcast traffic, but not from a malicious actor invoking the client send a request directly the the attacker.

Not catching any broadcast hashes without invoking from the client.

Comment: Welcome to the community. All of your changes were made in Group Policy Manager?

Comment: Yes, using gpmc.msc and edited the default domain policy

Comment: If I were you I would probably take a look with Wireshark. This is some weird behaviour or a bug